# In .net core Restful API how to change URL format to get double parameter with single method name?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-webapi, restful-url

With these two formats of URL these codes work fine:

```
http://localhost:51996/weatherforecast/help/p1
http://localhost:51996/weatherforecast/help/p1/p2

[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet("help/{a}")]
    [Route("help")]
   
    public string help( string  a)
    {
        return "single param";
    }

    [HttpGet("help/{b}/{c}")]
    [Route("help")]
    public string help( string b,string c)
    {
        return "double param";
    }
}
```

But how can I change my routes or anything to work with this type of URL:

```
http://localhost:51996/weatherforecast/help?a=p1
http://localhost:51996/weatherforecast/help?b=p1&c=p2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are pulling from query string. So your routes are set up wrong. Try this:

```
[HttpGet, Route("help")]
public string help([FromQuery] string  a)
{
    return "single param";
}

[HttpGet, Route("help")]
public string help([FromQuery]string b, [FromQuery] string c)
{
    return "double param";
}
```

But, the issue here is you have to routes that are identical. By default query strings are **optional**. So both these could be called the same way, the framework wouldn't know which one to call.

Example: You could call `https://example.com/api/Controller/help`, and both these methods are acceptable endpoints for that request.

So you need a way to differentiate the two.

Either change the name of the endpoint:

```
[HttpGet, Route("helpA")]
public string helpA([FromQuery] string  a)
{
    return "single param";
}

[HttpGet, Route("helpBC")]
public string helpBC([FromQuery]string b, [FromQuery] string c)
{
    return "double param";
}

// https://www.example.com/api/Controller/helpA/?a=string
// https://www.example.com/api/Controller/helpBC/?b=string1&c=string2
```

Or, you could change the path and make the strings *required*:

```
[HttpGet, Route("help/{a}")]

public string helpA(string  a)
{
    return "single param";
}

[HttpGet, Route("help/{b}/{c}")]
public string helpBC(string b, string c)
{
    return "double param";
}

// https://www.example.com/api/Controller/help/string
// https://www.example.com/api/Controller/help/string1/string2
```

Another thing you could do is combine all three, then make sure your documentation explains that they should use one or the other:

```
[HttpGet, Route("help")]
public string helpABC(
    [FromQuery]string a, [FromQuery]string b, [FromQuery]string c)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(a)){
        // b and c must not be null or empty
    }
    // etc...
}
```